# "he carried on"

Tags: meaning

Last Scene of All

> After John Calleron was hit **he carried on** in a kind of twilight of the
>   mind. Things grew dimmer and calmer; harsh outlines of events became
>   blurred; memories came to him; there was a singing in his ears like
>   far-off bells. Things seemed more beautiful than they had a while ago;
>   to him it was for all the world like evening after some quiet sunset,
>   when lawns and shrubs and woods and some old spire look lovely in the
>   late light, and one reflects on past days. Thus he carried on, seeing
>   things dimly. And what is sometimes called "the roar of battle," those
>   aerial voices that snarl and moan and whine and rage at soldiers, had
>   grown dimmer too. It all seemed further away, and littler, as far
>   things are. He still heard the bullets: there is something so
>   violently and intensely sharp in the snap of passing bullets at short
>   ranges that you hear them in deepest thought, and even in dreams. He
>   heard them, tearing by, above all things else. The rest seemed fainter
>   and dimmer, and smaller and further away. He did not think he was very
>   badly hit, but nothing seemed to matter as it did a while ago. Yet he
>   carried on.

This is from "Tales of War" by Lord Dunsany.

I do not understand what "he carried on" means.

Does it mean "he was carried on a strecher"?

Comment: Did you check this:http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/carry-on_1.

Comment: Thak you for your answer. I have got the meaning.

Comment: Why am I strongly feeling that there should be a *comma* between *'hit'* and *'he'*?

Comment: Because you are in a kind of twilight, Maulik.

Answer (score 1):

I am copying the below materials Directly from [Macmillan Online Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/carry-on_1)

> **carry on something**
>
> [ Transitive , Intransitive ] carry on something to continue doing something

Thus, in your context it means he continued moving forward. (he continued on his way)